# Remove only leading zeros from sorted dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary, leading-zero

This is my code

```
file_name = input()

shows = {}


with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 2):
        season = lines[i].strip('\n')
        name = lines[i+1].strip('\n')
        if(season in shows):
            shows[season].append(name)
        else:
            shows[season] = [name]
    
    
    with open('output_keys.txt', 'w+') as f:
        for key in sorted (shows.keys()):
            f.write('{}: {}\n'.format(key, '; '.join(shows.get(key))))
            print('{}: {}'.format(key, '; '.join(shows.get(key))))
      
    titles = []      
    for title in shows.values():
        titles.extend(title)
        
    with open('output_titles.txt', 'w+') as f:
        for title in sorted(titles):
            f.write('{}\n'.format(title))
            print(title)
```

The problem is with my `output_keys` files, leading zeros is the only differing output:

[image: Leading zeros is the only differing output]

I've tried using `.strip('0')` after the key But then that also removes the trailing zero and messes up the numbers that end in zero.

Comment: BTW you can use `shows = defaultdict(lambda: [])` to remedy the need for the `if(season in shows)` song-and-dance. It would allow you to unconditionally do `shows[season].append(name)`. If no array already exists, the default dict would make an empty array for you.

Comment: @Alexander: You don't need to use `shows = defaultdict(lambda: [])` — when `shows = defaultdict(list)` would work and is the usual way of doing it.

Comment: @martineau Neato, cool!

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I had no idea about default dictionaries

Comment: @Alexander: FYI it works because classes are callable in Python (it's how instances of them are created).

Comment: @martineau Yep, makes sense, just forgot about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change this line:

```
f.write('{}: {}\n'.format(key, '; '.join(shows.get(key))))
```

to this:

```
f.write('{}: {}\n'.format(key.lstrip("0"), '; '.join(shows.get(key))))
```

`lstrip("0")` will remove a `"0`" only if it as the start/left of a string.

Here are some examples to make that clearer:

```
>>>"07: Gone with the Wind, Rocky".lstrip('0')
'7: Gone with the Wind, Rocky'
>>>"17: Gone with the Wind, Rocky".lstrip('0')
'17: Gone with the Wind, Rocky'
```